# Django conditional javascript file in template causes missing staticfile error in production only

Tags: django

I have a conditional in a template used by several views which will include a js file if passed in by the view:

in the template:

```
{% if js_file %}
  {% block inner_js %}
    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="{% static js_file %}"></script>
  {% endblock inner_js %}
{% endif %}
```

which is eg used by a view by:

```
.......
context = {'title': 'Sign up',
               'form': form,
               'js_file': 'js/supplier.js'}
    return render(request, 'pages/signup.html', context)
```

This produces no errors in development, but when pushed to production I get the error:

```
ValueError at /users/example/
Missing staticfiles manifest entry for ''
```

If I remove the template if block above then this error dissapears (and works fine for those views which use the template without a js file).
I would rather not have to create a new version of the template for every view which uses a js file, is their a better way to fix this? (seems a bit of a weird error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can conditionally include/exclude a block as you're doing. If you put the `if` tags inside the `block`, it will only include the `<script>` tag when the variable `js_file` is populated.

If you're conditionally including this block to override another block called `inner_js` in a template higher up, you can do something like this to achieve the same results:

```
{% block inner_js %}
    {% if js_file %}
        <script ...></script>
    {% else %}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock inner_js %}
```

`{{ block.super }}` is the equivalent of calling Python's `super` in a class, and allows for block extensions in templates that extend a base.

Comment: Thanks I had to change the if condition from what you had originally, but yes that now works.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I derped! Thanks for fixing, and glad it helped :)